# How to communicate between User and Server via https

Tags: security, authentication, web, encryption, https

I am working on a Test-Page which has a working login functionality. On the server side every password is encrypted. I am wondering if the password the user enters should be encrypted before it gets send to the server backend or is this not necessary as the Test-Page uses HTTPS.

As you can see in the screenshot, username/ email and password gets sent to the server as Route Request Payload, both the email and the password are perfectly readable in the inspector tools. Screenshot:
[Network request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeYGP.png)

If an encryption is necessary even though https is used, how would the decryption of the password that the server gets would work? (No code needed just the explanation of the concept would be great then)

Thank you for your answers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for another layer of encryption. SSL/TLS (and by extend HTTPS) ensures that the packages that leave your computer are encrypted, therefore no one, say an attacker who can intercept the user's or server's network traffic, can read or modify the HTTP traffic in cleartext between server-client, as you can with the inspectors tools, and therefore capture the transmitted credentials.

However, make sure that you use robust security certificates, issued by a CA. Self-signed certificate or certificates that cannot be verified by trusted CAs leave the connection between client-server open to MiTM attacks.